# VM UEFI firmware does not recognize SCSI devices

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, uefi, libvirt

I am creating a virtual machine using `virt-manager`. I've set the firmware to UEFI, and changed both the virtual disk and CD drive to use VirtIO SCSI, instead of the default virtio-blk disk and SATA CD drive.

Upon clicking “Begin Installation”, TianoCore does not find any bootable drives, instead falling back to IPv4 PXE.

I've checked “Enable boot menu”, rebooted the VM, and pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> to get to the boot menu. The boot menu only shows three options: IPv4 PXE, IPv6 PXE, and UEFI shell.

My virtual CD drive has the OS installation disc image loaded, both before and after checking “Enable boot menu”. The VM host is x86-64. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I forgot to add the VirtIO SCSI controller when configuring the new VM. Adding it allowed my VM to boot into the CD drive and my virtual disk, so I can proceed to install my OS.